# Obfuscated connections in sqlyog

Tags: macos, sqlyog

I've changed my computer in work, now I have macbook. On previous computer I used to sqlyog, but on mac I'd like to use sequel pro. And I have problem - exported file with connections (*.sycs) have obfuscated password. Is it possible to decrypt passwords or other way to import those connections in sequel pro?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would like to say is the SQLyog is a windows application. If you need to use SQLyog on [mac then this would be useful](http://faq.webyog.com/content/31/181/en/can-i-use-sqlyog-on-a-mac.html)...